# (AngularJS) ng-options not populating despite ng-model and previously working syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

**Solved**: Two part issue. As pointed out by Veera the model was not being stored correctly in the controller, and the major issue was to do with the Smart Table injection in the module declaration.

---

Previously my code below managed to produce a list from a drop down menu in ng-options. After several seemingly unrelated changes were made it is now not working and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I understand a lot of people have an issue with ng-model in the select element so unless I've made a mistake and missed some syntax there I do not think this is the issue as it was working.

I am trying to populate the list with a "Ref Number" from an array in the controller. There may be some typos in variable names and data where I've changed them from the ones I'm using in my actual project.

```css
var reqWebApp = angular.module('reqWebApp', ['smart-table']);

    reqWebApp.controller('reqAppController', function reqAppController($scope) {
        $scope.requests = [
           {
                ref : "000455",
                status : "requested",
                prod : "BLEH",
                prodRef : "NAH8754",
                prodSite : "BLEHTON"
            }
            {
                ref : "003005",
                status : "requested",
                prod : "REDACTED",
                prodRef : "NA78546",
                prodSite : "REDVILLE"
            }
        ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="reqWebbApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pre-Acceptance</title>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../app.js"></script>
    <style>
        table { width: 90%; }
        input { width: 95%; }
        select { width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="reqAppController">
    <div style="display:inline">Pre-Accept Existing Request |
        <table style="display:inline-table; width: 5%" border="1" >
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Ref No.
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <select ng-model="references"
                            ng-options="request.ref for request in requests">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='../home/homepage.html'">ACCEPT</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='../home/homepage.html'">HOME</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for anyone's time to look through it.
Connor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ng-model as object and declare in controller

`HTML`

```
 <select ng-model="selected.selectedReference"
  ng-options="request.ref for request in requests">
   <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

`JS`

```
 $scope.selected = {};
```

Comment: Thank you! This combined with something I discovered in the Inspector in browser solved my issue. Smart table module was being injected wrong causing part of the problem and the model problem has fixed part of my issues later in the app.